# MySQL Using Group By to get unique values from description field and splitting on separator

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

Say I have this table of car sales:

```
DESCRIPTION       AMOUNT
--------------    -------
Ford: Tarus       $10,000
Honda: Accord     $11,000
Honda: Accord     $12,000
Chevy: Equinox    $13,000
Ford: Explorer    $14,000
Ford: Explorer    $15,000
Dodge: Dart       $16,000
Ford: Explorer    $17,000
```

If I want to see the total money brought in by each unique description I could say:

```
SELECT description, count(description) AS sales_count, SUM(amount) AS total_amount
FROM car_sales
GROUP BY description
ORDER BY total_amount DESC, sales_count DESC
```

and get a nice report like this:

```
DESCRIPTION       SALES_COUNT    TOTAL_AMOUNT
--------------    -----------    ------------
Ford: Explorer    3              $46,000
Honda: Accord     2              $23,000
Dodge: Dart       1              $16,000
Chevy: Equinox    1              $13,000
Ford: Tarus       1              $10,000
```

Now notice how my description is just the make and model separated by a colon. I can't change the way the description column is formatted but **I would like to get a response that shows a breakdown by make and then also by model. Kinda like splitting it on the `: colon`.** How would I write my SQL query to do this and get a table like this?

```
DESCRIPTION       SALES_COUNT    TOTAL_AMOUNT
--------------    -----------    ------------
Ford              4              $56,000
   Explorer       3              $46,000
   Tarus          1              $10,000
Honda             2              $23,000
   Accord         2              $23,000
Dodge             1              $16,000
   Dart           1              $16,000
Chevy             1              $13,000
   Equinox        1              $13,000
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: I'm using MySQL. Also as a side-note I'm programming in PHP (even though that doesn't matter because I would like to get my response back purely from the query).

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want using the `with rollup` option on `group by` (supported by both MySQL and SQL Server).  In MySQL, you can do this as:

```
SELECT substring_index(description, ':', 1) as make,
       substring_index(description, ':', 2) as model,
       count(description) AS sales_count, SUM(amount) AS total_amount
FROM car_sales cs
GROUP BY substring_index(description, ':', 1),
         substring_index(description, ':', 2) with rollup;
```

This is not *exactly* the output you are requesting.  This puts the make and model in separate columns, and includes an overall total.

You cannot use `order by` with `rollup`, alas.  You can do this if you use a subquery.  However, that probably won't do what you want, because it will order *all* the rows, including the ones with the summary values.

Comment: I think that will be EXACTLY what I'm looking for Gordon! Appreciate the response and I'm going to check it out right now.

Comment: Gordon, I was just testing this out and it works well with just the GROUP BY but when I add the ORDER BY statements I get an error that says "Incorrect usage of CUBE/ROLLUP and ORDER BY". I am testing the query using PHPMyAdmin (if that makes a difference).